# How to get single quotes inside a javascript variable (=function parameter) escaped?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm writing javascript with php like:

```
echo '<a class="'.$classTag.'" href="javascript: OpenModalDialog(\''.$MenuItem['table_name'].'\', \''.($MenuItem['where_clause']).'\');"><span>View Data</span></a>';
```

This results in this:

```
echo '<a class="'.$classTag.'" href="javascript: OpenModalDialog('input_lijstwerk_401', ' WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Datum, '%Y%m') = '201606'');"><span>View Data</span></a>';
```

The problem is in the variable: $MenuItem['where_clause'] with the single quotes inside the signature of the openModalDialog:
' WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Datum, '%Y%m') = '201606''

I have tried with json_encode, htmlspecialchars. We are working with PHP7

I hope that someone can help me out this problem.

Thanks,

Nico

Comment: I'd say it is generally a bad idea to put SQL in Javascript. If you really want to do it anyway, take a look at a decent template engine (don't `echo` your HTML/JS).

Comment: You want to JSON-encode a string (for Javascript syntax) in an HTML attribute… see the duplicate.

Comment: you may look for function `addslashes` but as Brat said SQL in javascript is very bad idea

Comment: I don't know why it is a bad idea to put SQL in javascript. I open a Modaldialog

Comment: On this moment the answers are not working in my case, so why is this marked as duplicate? And why is it a bad idea to put SQL in javascript, because I open a modaldiaglog to stay on the page and get the data into excel. If build the piece of SQL in javascript by discrete variables, than it is working. But what I want to know is it possible to get quotes inside a variable? If not than I have another possibility, to get it working.